# Can I create fstream before main?

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
ofstream fout(argv[1]);
```

main function

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
//I try to add "new word" fstream file
fout<<"new words"<<endl;
}
```

How can I do this? The bottom one didn't work either. It is necessery. It must be before main function

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string argument;
ofstream fout(argument]);
```

main function

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
argument=argv[1]
fout<<"new words"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884978/how-to-printing-cout-to-file-instead-of-console-or-taking-argv-before-main-funct)? You're going to get the same suggestions here.

Comment: Why must it "be before main function"? This seems like an arbitrary requirement that simply cannot be fulfilled. You can't open a file based on the parameter of a function that _hasn't been called yet_

Comment: "Can I create fstream before main?" Yes. "Can I use `argv` before main?" No.

Comment: No, it's not the same question, but when I saw that question I wondered about it.

Comment: It might be possible with an OS API such as `GetCommandLine`. _Might_ —the documentation doesn't say whether it's valid before `main`. Even if that works, I can't imagine a useful requirement that would necessitate it.

Comment: *"didn't work"* -- please give a more detailed description than this. One of the goals of this site is to build a *searchable* archive of questions and answers. How is someone else with the same problem supposed to find this question? The vast majority of questions on this site involve something not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize your `fout` before you know what `argv` is. So, in some sense, impossible. However, you can initialize it with nothing, and `open` it later when you get your `argv`:

```
ofstream fout;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    fout.open(argv[1]);
    fout<<"new words"<<endl;
}
```

This way, the global `fout` is accessible to all functions defined after it. However, there is a short period, before opening it in `main`, when `fout` is invalid. This is the best you can do, from a logical point of view.

Comment: @b219 note that you now have a global variable and have to keep a close eye on it. It's lying around totally exposed and anyone can mess with it. Even code in other translation units. This makes debugging and auditing the correctness o the code  more difficult than necessary, so it needs to have a big pay off that makes the suffering it can cause worthwhile.

Comment: I am aware of this, I just started c ++ and I have a solitare my assignment that I need to catch up shortly. I am aware that this is not correct, but I had to do it for the my assignment to work.